# Дублирование элемента в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть `ListView`, в котором при нажатии на `item` появляется кнопка, после чего при пролистывании такая же кнопка появляется на других элементах списка. Т.е. если нажать на первый элемент и начать пролистывать, то эта же кнопка видна на элементах номер 11, 21 и т.д. Получается, что кнопка появляется на элементах через каждых 10 элементов( количество элементов списка которые помещаются на одном экране ). До этого листенер у меня был вынесен за пределы блока `if()` но это ничего не изменило, в чем может быть проблема?

Вот **пример** моего адаптера:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "ContactListAdapter";

    ArrayList<Contact> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ViewHolder preHolder;
    private ViewHolder secondHold;


    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ContactList contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        list = contactList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<ContactCaling> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private View rootView;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvInitials;
        private ImageView ivAvatart;
        private ImageView ivStatus;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain;
        private RelativeLayout onlineButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout timeoutButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_icon_phone;
        private String contactName;
        private boolean isShow;

        private ContactCaling contactCaling;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rootView = convertView;

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);


            holder.tvName = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_name);
            holder.tvInitials = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_initials);
            holder.ivAvatart = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_contact_avatar);
            holder.ivStatus = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status);
            holder.relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_parent);
            holder.relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_main);
            holder.onlineButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_icon_phone = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_icon_phone);
            holder.timeoutButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_busy_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner);

            /**-------------Item listener---------------**/


            holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (preHolder == null || (secondHold != null && secondHold.equals(holder))) {
                        if (MyApplication.isOnline()) {
                            int buttonTranslation = -holder.onlineButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                            holder.onlineButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            secondHold = null;
                        } else {
                            int buttonTranslation = -holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                            holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            secondHold = null;
                        }

                    }

                    if (preHolder != null) {

                        if (MyApplication.isOnline()) {
                            int translate = preHolder.onlineButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;
                            preHolder.relativeLayoutMain
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(0)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            preHolder.onlineButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(translate)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                        } else {
                            int translate = preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;
                            preHolder.relativeLayoutMain
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(0)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(translate)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                        }

                    }

                    if (preHolder != null) {
                        preHolder = null;
                    } else {
                        preHolder = holder;
                    }
                    secondHold = holder;
                }

            });


            holder.isShow = false;
            holder.rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.contact = (Contact) getItem(position);
        holder.contactName = holder.contact.getDisplayName();

        holder.tvName.setText(holder.contactName);
        setIcons(position, holder);

        return holder.rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    private void setIconsMOCK(int position, ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.ivAvatart.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.identicon_default));
        String initials = extractInitials(holder);
        holder.tvInitials.setText(initials);
        holder.ivStatus.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.status_green));
    }


    private String extractInitials(ViewHolder holder) {
        String initials;
        String[] s = holder.contactName.split(" ");
        if (s.length == 1) {
            String char1 = String.valueOf(s[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
            initials = char1 + "";
            initials.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            String char1 = String.valueOf(s[0].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
            String char2 = String.valueOf(s[1].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
            initials = char1 + "" + char2;
            initials.toUpperCase();
        }

        return initials;
    }

}
```

Comment: Используйте RecyclerView - в нём пересоздание элементов нормально реализовано. А в вашем случае может помочь перенос всего кода, не относящегося к формированию холдера в конец метода `getView`. Ну и/или устанавливать кнопку по позиции в списке, а не только по нажатию.

Comment: т.е. использую RecyclerView  - эта проблема отпадет?

Comment: Не факт. Адаптер может не знать какой именно элемент вы хотите с кнопкой видеть. Вам надо что-то типа списка, коий будет хранить позиции элементов, на коих кнопка должна быть. После чего в `getView` проверять равенство текущей позиции с позициями в этом списке и исходя из этого убирать/показывать кнопку. главное не забыть, что и убирать тоже надо, не только добавлять.

Comment: Предположительно ты не обнуляешь что-то при отрисовке каждого пункта. Например у тебя кастомный пункт списка и кнопка должна появляться зависимо от условия - в начале отрисовки каждой строки ты обязательно должен скрывать кнопку и потом проверять нужно ли ее показать. Мне такая логика помогла.

Comment: ну у меня там есть некоторая логика по которой я скрываю или показывую кнопку, но я так понимаю вы немного о другом, можете в ответ набросать примерно то о чем вы говорите?